# To find a complex symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to find a complex symmetric matrix $A$ such that there is no unitary matrix $P \in U_n(\mathbb{C}) $ with $PAP^{*}$ diagonal.

I couldn't find one easily.

I know that the unitary matrix means $AA^{*}=I$  but then which property should I use to get the required matrix ?

Answer (score 2):

Try the matrix 
$$
\pmatrix{1&i\\i&-1},
$$
which cannot be diagonalized by *any* matrix.

Comment: Thanks. How should i generalize to $ n \times n $ matrix ?

Comment: @sammath By taking a block diagonal matrix with this one as the diagonal blocks and/or by appending zeros.